# Creating a Drop-down menu in the Sharepoint 2007 Left Navigation

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Basically I'm trying to figure out the best way to change the left navigation section in sharepoint 2007, the area that is also referred to as the 'quick launch bar'. I would like to implement a simple drop-down menu system. So you hover over a link and more appear. This may be very simple or may not be possible, so I figured I'd ask.

I would only like to change the navigation for one site, not everything. This is an intranet site not public facing. I'm not sure of the version but I think its enterprise.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

What you could do within the confines of SPDesigner is create a new master page for your site (or you could edit the current one, though I really, really don't recommend that). I would recommend making a copy of the default master, then going in and finding the ASP control for the quicklaunch bar (doing a search for QuickLaunchMenu should get you there). From there, make the following changes to the attributes of that tag:

- Change StaticDisplayLevels to 1.
- Change MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels to 1 as well.

This will make flyouts for any page based on that master. If you then set that as your default master page (either through the OOB Site Settings page or through Designer), all pages on the site will inherit that look.

See this helpful (whoa, not a common occurrence!) MS page for more reference:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms466994(v=office.12).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

http://spnavigationmenu.codeplex.com/

Comment: thanks for the solution. but do you know of a way to possibly get these changes made using only sharepoint designer? does anyone else have ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you can only do it in SP Designer, maybe modifing the masterpage for your single site and adding some jquery to the master page to add the navigation flyout.

There are several places on the internet where people have used jQuery to modify the quicklaunch.  Some of those might be a good start.